# psql console not accepting localization

Tags: linux, postgresql, console, debian, psql

I have encountered a strange problem on one of our machines.

It is a fresh install of Debian Squeeze, with Postgres 8.4.10.

I have a few localizations installed on the machine, locale -a gives this:

```
C
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
POSIX
swedish
sv_SE
sv_SE.iso88591
sv_SE.utf8
```

In the regular linux console I can use swedish localization (åäö works), but when I enter the psql console I can't use localized characters. Doesn't matter how I configure my terminal (tried just about every encoding I can think of).

The database itself works fine, I can input localized chars by making a SQL file and keep the inserts there. It's just no the most efficient way of doing it ;-)

Haven't run into this problem before, and I've installed quite a few machines. Does anyone have any idea of what could possibly be the cause of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're experiencing the problem explained in this bug report:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=608442

Summary: due to a licensing issue, psql is now linked to libedit instead of libreadline, and unfortunately libedit is broken/incomplete with regard to accented characters.
According to the report, a work-around is to launch psql with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libreadline.so.5 psql
```

or upgrade the **postgresql-common** package to version 114 or higher. Since it's not in the stable branch, the easiest way may be to switch to backports:

```
# aptitude -t squeeze-backports install postgresql-common
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the database encoding with `\l` then check the client encoding:

```
=> show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

If they do not match then change the client encoding to that of the database:

```
set client_encoding=iso88591;
```